# Android ToggleButton: resize text for fit into it

Tags: android, text-size, android-togglebutton

In my Android app i have several ToggleButton with a prefixed size and textsize:

```
<ToggleButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/filtro_toggle_bg"
    android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp14" >
```

Now i would assign dinamically textSize to toggle if text doesn't fit toggle. 
For example it happen that long words like "choccolate" doesn't fit into toggle, and is showed "choccol...".

Comment: Did you try AutoScale TextView? http://ankri.de/autoscale-textview/

Comment: My widget is a Toggle, not a textview

Comment: so...? ToggleButton extends from android.widget.TextView... adapt the library to your needs and that's it. http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:ems` attribute (how mutch 'M' shoud fit in) or set `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content` or both :)